# What could I do to make QGIS find all the plugins?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, ubuntu

I'm starting to use Ubuntu 12.10 and would like to get my QGIS running on it. Installation was fine but when I tried to add a package called Points to Paths the Plugin Manager was unabled to find it. Indeed there appeared to be only four plugins available on the two repositories that where activated by default (The QGIS Oficial Repository and the orphans repository). So after activating third part repositories there seem to be more plugins but the desired one doesnt appear.

Is there a way to install these plugins manually on the console? Or what could I do to make QGIS find all the plugins? Has anybody expirienced similar problems?

Comment: problem is not all work all the time. The plugin manager has improved over the past few releases though still needs tweaking.

Comment: @Mapperz would you say it is better on MS?

Comment: its more stable in ubuntu than win7/8 from experience.

Answer (score 2):

ok I got it...changed Allowed Plugins in the options tab to "Show all plugins, even those marked as experimental". Hope this helps someone.